# Why does Mikey attack the INS Agent?

Tags: character, men-in-black

In the original Men in Black movie, at the beginning of the movie Agent K and Agent D find the alien [Mikey](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/Mikey) hiding among immigrants being brought into the United States illegally.  K and D take him out of sight and reveal him to be an alien and interrogate him.  Mikey seems calm and rational, however, an INS agent walks over the hill and Mikey freaks out and charges the agent, forcing K to shoot him.

Why would he turn violent all of a sudden and attack the agent?  If he was already violent, why didn't he attack K or D immediately, where he would have a better chance of surviving?

Answer (score 4):

Because he was pissed and it was all because of INS agents that Mikey got in trouble. Else he might have got away with it. And when he sees INS agent again while getting interrogated by K & D, he lost his temper and attacked the easy target out of anger.

Comment: Note that it was K & D; this is before J replaced D.

Comment: Also note that Mikey wasn't wearing his diguise then. It's not impossible that his offensive move was _defensive_ in nature, e.g. if people shot at him for no good reason (other than being an alien) in the past. Given K & D's fairly unsurprised response to Mikey's attack, it's possible that Mikey's behavior is expected (based on his species' fight or flight instinct).